# Как сделать, чтобы обозреватель принял php код.

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

У меня стоит Windows XP SP3. Когда я тестирую php в локальном сервере, в денвере, он не согласуется с браузером, он показывает только код, который я писал.

Answer (score 4):

Для начала изучить как вообще работает серверный язык и понять, что к браузеру он не имеет никакого отношения. Если ваш код выводится в браузер без обработки, то это означает, что апач ничего не знает о .php расширении либо(и) о том как его обрабатывать...

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Самый простой способ (на Windows точно) всё один раз быстро сделать, это установить XAMPP. Будет и работающая mysql и запущенный apache и всё-всё-всё. Весит около 400 мегов зато очень быстро и не надо разбираться. Раз уж вы начали писать, не разобравшись, как что работает.
В сети куча инструкций и видео по поводу того, как именно это делается.

Comment: а еще лучше поставить ОС семейства nix т.к. apache изначально писался именно под linux

Comment: Кто спорит. Опыт положительный появится, но раз человек уже решил писать на php, пусть начнёт прямо сейчас)

Comment: спасибо что откликнулись

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вы только начали учить PHP то задам вопрос - расширение у файла точно .php?
Это довольно частая ошибка начинающих, php код в файлах с форматом .html не отрабатывается.

А вообще - про nix чистая правда, разрабатывать стоит именно на нем.

Comment: да на какой угодно оси можно разрабатывать. Одно из преймуществ апача - кросплатформенность!

Comment: Гвозди тоже можно забивать не только молотком xD

Comment: а чем принципиально пхп+апач отличается на никсах и на форточках?

Comment: По мне - так проще потрахаться с установкой апача под Win, чем установкой всех браузеров под *nix. Или Вы доверяете тест кроссбраузерности всяким левым программам?

Comment: Если вы верстальщик то конечно вам будет лучше в Windows, а если вы программист, зачем вам все браузеры обьясните пожалуйста?..

К тому-же все легко и просто ставится на nix'ах, вино в помощь, ах да, еще забыл добавить - <b>знание linux большой плюс для любого php программиста</b>, я не буду щас описывать и рассказывать почему, просто тупо посмотрите по требованиям на вакансии и вы все поймете...<br>
PS:лидирующую должность php разраба где не требуется знание nix вообще найти наверное нереально...

Comment: Ну вот я программист и реально мне за 6 лет знание никсов(именно в web-среде) пригодилось пару раз, и то это все в гугле находится на раз. Есть еще вин-сервера с апачем, там эти знания не нужны вообще. Ну и вообще на домашний комп эту, эм, ось ставить не рекомендую, если у вас все хорошо в личной жизни и большинство времени вы все-таки хотите работать, а не "настраивать рабочее место") Имхо, конечно)

Comment: Сразу чувствуется что отписался "великий знаток linux'a :)"

Comment: Моя должность именуется "Ведущий программист". И да, я умею обращаться с unix-клонами (unix-подобными не пользуюсь в принципе - ибо я не считаю зазорным платить за нужный мне софт, а нормальной мультимедийности от *nix не добьешься). Что касается вопроса, зачем программисту кроссбраузерность - верстка версткой - с ней всегда много глюков, а про контроль кроссбраузерности JS забыли?

Comment: @Sh4dow, принципиальное отличие: чувствительность к регистру имен файлов. =) Будем спорить?

Comment: а про вино вы читали?^^<br> Что вам мешает поставить IE tester на нем? Остальные же адекватные браузеры аля ФФ, Хром, Опера вообще предоставляют свой продукт прямо под линь, в чем собственно сложности то?<br>
Откровенно говоря удивлен что для "ведущего программиста" не очевидно что все эти "проблемы", мягко говоря, решаются на раз, не?